# Converting DateTime to an integer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, time, integer

How would you convert a randomly generated time into an integer, This is how I have formatted my time;

```
StartTime = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongTime)
EndTime = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongTime)
Diff = (EndTime - StartTime.Subtract(TimeSpan))
```

So for example `Diff = "08:30:12"`

I want to be able to convert that to "8.30" as in 8 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: `8.30` is not an integer.

Comment: That’s just totally flawed. Why do you want a number (integer, floating point, whatever) anyway? And *if* at all, then 8:30 should be represented as 8.5 since 30 minutes correspond to half an hour, not 3/10 of an hour.

Answer (score 1):

8.30 is not an `Integer`.

However, you can use the [`TimeSpan.Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx) and [`TimeSpan.Minutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes.aspx) properties with `String.Format` if you want a string with the hours and the minutes parts:

```
String.Format("{0}.{1}", Diff.Hours, Diff.Minutes)
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/IHM2nx)

Comment: Or just `Diff.Format("hh.mm")`

Comment: @millimoose: `Diff` is a `TimeSpan` which has no `Format` method. You could use `Diff.ToString("hhmm")` which works, but only wihout the point.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want an **integer** representation of your Diff result.
Supposing that Diff is a TimeSpan structure, why not use simply?

```
 Dim x as Integer 
 x = Convert.ToInt32(Diff.TotalMinutes)
```

Of course I assume that the difference is never so big to overflow the integer

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
Dim d As Decimal
d = Diff.Hours + Diff.Minutes / 100D
```

100D gives a decimal that is needed for the division. Integer division 30/100 gives 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DateTime.DiffDate function, which returns a long

```
dim date1 as DateTime = Now
dim date2 as DateTime = Now.AddSeconds(-30600)  ' 8.5 hours ago
dim lHr as long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, date1, date2) '=-8
dim lMn as long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, date1, date2) '=-510
lHr = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, date2, date1)     ' = +8
lMn = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, date2, date1)   ' = +510
```

(there are other intervals, days, seconds etc. in DateDiff which would also come in handy) Note that there is no rounding up of your values. Makes number of minutes within hour easy

```
num_Minutes_Past_Hour = lMn - lHr * 60     ' = 30
```